# Format with the same value many times in a string

Tags: elisp, formatting

On python, you can repeat a value several times inside a string when formatting it:

```
>>> print "Hello, {name}, how are you, {name}?".format(name="George")
    "Hello, George, how are you, George?"
```

But I don't know how to achieve this with elisp. I'm trying to make a function that returns the GPLv3 copyright text (*This file is part of Foobar. Foobar is free software:*) with the name of any projectile project on it.

Answer (score 0):

Still another solution:

```
(let ((name "George"))
  (format "%s" (concat "Hello, " name ", how are you, " name "?")))
```